# MySQL: Exclude all users with at least 1 occurrence of a specific field value

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a MySQL report that includes only users who are students and who are not a teacher in any other course. Sometimes a user can be a student in one course and a teacher in another course. I want to completely exclude that user from my report.

```
User Table
userid   username
  1        Bob
  2        John
  3        Sally
  4        Suzy



Courses Table
courseid   coursename
  100      Geometry
  101      Literature
  102      Spanish

Enrollments Table
userid   courseid   role
   1        100     student
   1        101     teacher
   2        100     student
   2        102     student
   3        101     student
   3        102     student
   4        100     student
   4        102     teacher
```

The desired output would be:

```
username    coursename     role
  John        Geometry     student
  John        Spanish      student
  Sally       Literature   student
  Sally       Spanish      student
```

Bob and Suzy would not be included because they have a teacher role in at least one course.

```
SELECT u.username, c.coursename, e.role
FROM enrollments e
JOIN users u ON user.userid = e.userid
JOIN courses c ON c.courseid = e.courseid
WHERE e.role = 'student'
```

...isn't specific enough because it would include Bob and Suzy's enrollments where they are students.

I think I'm supposed to use a subjoin somehow, but that's beyond any query I've written so far. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT u.username, c.coursename, e.role
FROM enrollments e
JOIN users u ON user.userid = e.userid
JOIN courses c ON c.courseid = e.courseid
WHERE u.userid NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT userid FROM enrollments WHERE role = 'teacher')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
    select u.username,c.coursename,e.role
    from User as u
    inner join Enrollments as e
    on u.userid=e.userid
    inner join Courses as c
    on c.courseid=e.courseid
    -- where `condition`
```

Using `Inner Join` instead of regular `JOIN`

Comment: My real-life query joins a LOT of tables, and I couldn't quickly work out which ones to INNER JOIN. Thanks a lot for the suggestion though! I may try it in the future.